# Wordpress POT file ignored

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

I generated `pot` file for my theme with wp-cli.

```
wp i18n make-pot wp-content/themes/my-theme/
```

Then I copied it and change name to `pl_PL.pot` which is my native language, but even when I change value in this file on my website i still see English version instead of Polish.

```
#: tools/customizer.php:5
msgid "Theme options"
msgstr "Opcje motywu"
```

I use `__()` and `_e()` function. I added `Text Domain: my-theme` to `style.css` and set polish language in wordpress setting but still not work.

Comment: I know that this question could be considered `old`, but the answer here is probably that you need to name the file like this: `plugin-prefix-lang_LANG.pot` for example in your case it would be `my-theme-pl_PL.pot`